# A global planner using a Roadmap graph

Tags: navigation, ros-melodic, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a global planner in ROS1 that can deal with a predefined Roadmap graph to make the robot move on its edges.
I think this would be a very useful thing but can not find anything in that area.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/316768/a-global-planner-using-a-roadmap-graph/) by [ct2034](https://answers.ros.org/users/12141/ct2034/) on ROS Answers with karma: 862 on 2019-02-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2019-02-26**:
Is a Roadmap graph a specific data structure?

**Comment by [ct2034](https://answers.ros.org/users/12141/ct2034/) on 2019-02-26**:
No. I mean just a generic geometric graph that is *not* a gridmap. For example from a 2D PRM etc.
It would be good to use something existing like a Boost Graphs, Networkx or GraphML.
And it would also be a good feature to get this graph via a topic (similar to the map topic, but a graph)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To answer my own question. I made this here: https://github.com/ct2034/miriam/tree/master/roadmaps/odrm_global_planner

Currently, I am in the process of releasing/cleaning it up.

---

Originally posted by [ct2034](https://answers.ros.org/users/12141/ct2034/) with karma: 862 on 2019-12-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0